# How to wrap a c++ class with an opencv object with c++/cli

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, c++-cli, wrapper

I would like to wrap a complex c++ class which used opencv object with c++/cli for using in c# and vb. I'm using Visual Studio 2015. I'm using the x64 versions of of the OpenCV library and compiling also to x64.

Following is the header.h file of a small test class, just as an example:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace std;

class compC
{
public:
    compC(int * pInt, int arrSize);
    int sumArray();
private:
    vector<int> vec;
    cv::Mat img;
};
```

This is going to be compiled as a win32-application to a .lib file without any problems.

The example wrapper class (wrapper.h) would look like:

```
#pragma once

#include "../ConsoleApplication1/header.h"
#include "../ConsoleApplication1/body.cpp"

using namespace System;

namespace WrapperLibrary {

    public ref class WrapperClass
    {
    public:
        WrapperClass(int * pInt, int arraySize);
        int getSum();
    private:
        compC * pcC;
        int sum;
    };
}
```

The second class would be compiled as a dll with /clr (as c++/cli project).

First I got an error that opencv.hpp could not be find and had to add the include directory of opencv in to the wrapper project. But I cannot compile it and get a lot of errors, mainly pointing to linking problems "unresolved external problems ..." in connection with the opencv-mat object.

If I remove the lines

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
```

and

```
cv::Mat img;
```

in the test class (header.h) all will be fine.

What did I made wrong? How can I wrap those c++ class with c++/cli?